# Algorithms from R-statistics package Caret R Package- LVQ algorithm, is there similar in Python

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, scikit-learn, r

In the R-statistics package : Caret R Package, they have the LVQ algorithm that is used
for the purpose of "Feature Selection".
I have used this to do some data science in R-stats over 6 years ago.

I am searching all over the web, and the only reference I can find for LVQ is in terms of LVQ being used as a CLASSIFIER in python and that is it.

SO hope someone can tell me if there is "LVQ-Feature Selection" algorithm in PYTHON like there is
in R-stats package : Caret R Package.

Hope someone knows if a Python library Exists for this or not.

Comment: Have you looked at the [`sklvq` package](https://sklvq.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html)?